# How to change a column in a matrix made of tuples?

Tags: python, list, optimization, tuples

I am unsure as to the cost of transforming a matrix of tuples into a list form which is easier to manipulate. The main priority is being able to change a column of the matrix as *fast* as possible

I have a matrix in the form of

`[(a,b,c),(d,e,f),(g,h,i)]`

which can appear in any size of n x m but for this example we'll take  3x3 matrix.
my main goal is to be able to change the values of any column in the matrix (only one at a time) (eg (b,e,h)).

my initial attempt was to transform the matrix into a list ie

`[[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i]]`

which would be easier

but I feel that it would be costly in terms of transforming every tuple into a list and back into a tuple.

My main question could be how to optimize this to its fullest?

Comment: Why to they have to be tuples? I wouldn't worry about optimizing things unless is becomes a problem — avoid premature optimization.

Comment: _"transforming every tuple into a list and back into a tuple."_: Do you _have_ to transform them back? Tuples are immutable, as you've probably already found out, so it's better to leave them as lists if you anticipate hving to change elements.

Comment: If changing elements of the matrix is a one-off operation, you can just change the tuple for that row. `r = list(mtx[row]); r[col] = new_val; mtx[row] = tuple(r)`

Comment: as much as i would like to return a list i can't return in a list form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [37]: def change_column_list_comp(old_m, col, value):
    ...:     return [
    ...:         tuple(list(row[:col]) + [value] + list(row[col + 1:]))
    ...:         for row in old_m
    ...:     ]
    ...:

In [38]: def change_column_list_convert(old_m, col, value):
    ...:     list_m = list(map(list, old_m))
    ...:     for row in list_m:
    ...:         row[col] = value
    ...:
    ...:     return list(map(tuple, list_m))
    ...:

In [39]: m = [tuple('abc'), tuple('def'), tuple('ghi')]

In [40]: %timeit change_column_list_comp(m, 1, 2)
2.05 µs ± 89.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [41]: %timeit change_column_list_convert(m, 1, 2)
1.28 µs ± 121 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Looks like converting to a `list`, modifying the values, and converting back to `tuple` is faster. Note that this may not be the most efficient way of writing these functions.

However, these functions seem to start to converge as we scale up our matrix.

```
In [6]: m_100k = [tuple(string.printable)] * 100_000

In [7]: %timeit change_column_list_comp(m_100k, 1, 2)
163 ms ± 3.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [8]: %timeit change_column_list_convert(m_100k, 1, 2)
117 ms ± 5.67 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [42]: m_1m = [tuple(string.printable)] * 1_000_000

In [43]: %timeit change_column_list_comp(m_1m, 1, 2)
1.72 s ± 74.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [44]: %timeit change_column_list_convert(m_1m, 1, 2)
1.24 s ± 84.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

At the end of the day you should be using the right tools for the job. While it's not really in the OP, it's just worth mentioning that `numpy` is simply the better way to go.

```
In [13]: m_np = np.array([list('abc'), list('def'), list('ghi')])

In [17]: %timeit m_np[:, 1] = 2; m_np
610 ns ± 48.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [20]: m_np_100k = np.array([[string.printable] * 100_000])

In [21]: %timeit m_np_100k[:, 1] = 2; m_np_100k
545 ns ± 63.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [22]: m_np_1m = np.array([[string.printable] * 1_000_000])

# This might be using cached data
In [23]: %timeit m_np_1m[:, 1] = 2; m_np_1m
515 ns ± 31.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

# Avoiding cache
In [24]: %timeit m_np_1m[:, 4] = 9; m_np_1m
557 ns ± 37.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

This might not be the fairest comparison as we're manually returning the matrix, but you can see there is significant improvement.